# How to move this Selected Item Changed Events from Pages into ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code for handling Item Selected on ListView and once selected will redirect to other page with an Id.

I can do this in Pages level BUT I want to move this to ViewModel. How do I do this?

**ActivitiesPage.xaml:**

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="TbSearch" Icon="search.png" Command="{Binding SearchBtnClicked}"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="TbAdd" Icon="add.png" Command="{Binding AddBtnClicked}"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <!--<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="LvActivities_ItemSelected">-->
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SelectedItem="{Binding NameSelectedItem}">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <extended:InfiniteScrollBehavior IsLoadingMore="{Binding IsBusy}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <Grid Padding="5" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">
                <!-- Footer HeightRequest must be 0 when not visible -->
                <Grid.Triggers>
                    <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Grid.Triggers>
                <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="Crimson" FontSize="Large"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Footer>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ActivitiesPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class ActivitiesPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities;

    public ActivitiesPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ActivityViewModel(Navigation);
    }

    private void LvActivities_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedActivity = e.SelectedItem as Activity;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityDetailPage(selectedActivity.Id));
    }
}
```

**ActivityViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class ActivityViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private const int PageSize = 10;
    private int totalRecords;
    private readonly ApiService apiService = new ApiService();
    public InfiniteScrollCollection<Activity> Items { get; }

    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SearchBtnClicked
    {

        protected set;
        get;
    }

    public ICommand AddBtnClicked
    {

        protected set;
        get;
    }

    public ActivityViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        Items = new InfiniteScrollCollection<Activity>
        {       
            OnLoadMore = async () =>
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                int page = Items.Count / PageSize;
                ActivityResult activityResult = await apiService.GetActivities("-CreatedDate", page+1, PageSize);
                IsBusy = false;
                return activityResult.Results;
            },
            OnCanLoadMore = () =>
            {
                return Items.Count < totalRecords;
            }
        };
        DownloadDataAsync();

        this.SearchBtnClicked = new Command(async () => await GotoSearchPage());
        this.AddBtnClicked = new Command(async () => await GotoAddPage());


    }

    public async Task GotoSearchPage()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivitySearchPage());
    }

    public async Task GotoAddPage()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityAddPage());
    }

    private async Task DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        ActivityResult items = await apiService.GetActivities("-CreatedDate", 1, PageSize);
        totalRecords = items.Metadata.TotalRecords;
        Items.AddRange(items.Results);
    }
```

Comment: Create a `SelectedItem` property in the view model that can be bound to the list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SelectedItem` property in the view model

```cs
private Activity selectedActivity = null;
public Activity SelectedItem { 
    get { return selectedActivity; }
    set {
        selectedActivity = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(); //assumption here
        if(selectedActivity != null) {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityDetailPage(selectedActivity.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

that can be bound to the list view

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

    <!-- ...omitted for brevity -->

</ListView>
```

This will allow the event handler to be removed from the View's code behind.